# Notation of a technical drawing

Tags: technical-drawing

can someone explain me what 1/8" or 1/16" means in the image below?
[image]

Comment: american units of measure -- 1/8" is 0.125 inch ;  1/16" is 0.0625 inch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1/16" refers to the thickness of the circle containing the letters, which appears to be 4 3/8" diameter. 1/8" refers to the radius of the cylinder top under the lettered circle.

If your question refers to the " notation, Pete W's comment addresses that aspect. " is inches Imperial measurement.